# How to find Durbin Watson critical values given a large number of observations and regressors?

Tags: multiple-regression, python, autocorrelation, durbin-watson-test

This is my first question here. I am working on a simple multiple regression model, wherein I have 23 regressors and 122 observations. But for this, I am not able to find the Dl and Du values which I can use in the test for Durbin-Watson statistic to have an opinion about the presence of positive serial correlation. I don't have stats background, am purely a Pythonista and have done a lot of research to generate them and failed so far.

How to generate the Dl and Du values? Preferably via python!

Here is the snapshot of the regression summary, for better info:

[image]

Dl and Du values I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: What is DI and Du?

Comment: Hello @Richard,  I have just added an image to the literature I am referring to. Is there any other way you can conduct DW hypothesis test other than this?